# Bash script to read a list of integers

Tags: bash, list, input

I'm writing a bash script and I need to take a list of integers from the user and do some calculations on them.

Something like:

```
echo -n "How many numbers?"
read numOfValues

echo -n "Enter $numOfValues numbers."

for (( i = 0; i < numOfValues; i++ ))
do

   # read and store integers

done

   # do calculations
```

Do I have to malloc an array? Or just make a linked list of something? I'm not to proficient in Bash so anything will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
read -p "How many numbers?" numOfValues

echo "Enter $numOfValues numbers."
arr=()
for (( i = 0; i < numOfValues; i++ ))
do
   read n
   arr+=( $n )
done

echo "${arr[@]}"
```

**Aletarnatively** you can read an array like this also:

```
read -p "Enter Aray: " -a array
2 3 5 7
# display the array
echo "${a[@]}"
2 3 5 7
```